# I make a memory game based in a tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an memory game base in a tutorial which you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ii0rPoiGkw)

Every thing was going ok until I got this exception:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   GameController.addgamepuzzles () (at Assets/memorygame/scripts/GameController.cs:43)

This is the line

```
gamepuzzles.Add(puzzles[index]);
```

This is My actual code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField]
private Sprite bgimage;

public Sprite[] puzzles;

public List<Sprite> gamepuzzles = new List<Sprite>();

public List<Button> btns = new List<Button>();



void Start () {
    GetButttons();
    AddListeners();
    addgamepuzzles();
    puzzles = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("Sprites/Candy");
}
void GetButttons()
{
    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PuzzleButton");

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++){
        btns.Add(objects[i].GetComponent<Button>());
        btns[i].image.sprite = bgimage;
    }
}

void addgamepuzzles(){
    int looper = btns.Count;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < looper; i++){

        if (index == looper / 2){
            index = 0;
        }

        gamepuzzles.Add(puzzles[index]);

        index++;
    }
}

void AddListeners(){
    foreach (Button btn in btns){
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => PickPuzzle());
    }
}

public void PickPuzzle(){
    string name = UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
    Debug.Log("you clicked a button with name: " + name);
}
}
```

This is my add buttons script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AddButtons : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField]
public Transform PuzzleFiled;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject btn;



void Awake () {

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        GameObject button = Instantiate(btn);
        button.name ="" +i;
        button.transform.SetParent(PuzzleFiled, false);
    }

}
}
```

The two scripts are attached to an empty `gameObject` call game manager.
Also i have a panel called Puzzle Field with grid layout element attach to it.
I have also a prefab with a button and image script on it.

Comment: Have you checked what is contained in the puzzles array? It seems to have fewer objects than you expect.

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos well i have check and in fact i have more sprites how can i load the sprites and avoid this error any suggestion will bee grateful

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for this. I can't see you code blowing up at the moment. Give me something I can run in a Console App please.

Comment: @Enigmativity Tank you for replay o just reedit to post more details about

Comment: for starters, put a debug.log(puzzles.length) in the start after you setup puzzles with your resources call, Im guessing it didnt find any

Comment: @BugFinder tank you , yes true but well i take out the funtion addgamepuzzle the images are all load in the field but if the funtion is active e stop because the out range

Comment: as I said, check how many it finds and puts in puzzles because the answer could be 0 ..

Comment: @roffymiranda - Please provide a [mcve] - something that we can run in a Console App.

Answer (score 0):

You're `index` is larger than the size of your puzzles array. I would guess the problem happens when you are populating your array:

```
puzzles = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites/Candy");
```

Are you sure that this is the correct directory as if this doesn't exist, is empty or is misspelled then the function will return nothing and your array will remain empty

Comment: Yes i am sure thats the directory is this one also wen i take the function addgamepuzzle it populate all the images

Comment: And the number of images is the same as the number of game objects returned here? `GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PuzzleButton");`

Comment: Well In fact the error was easy to find after to me to get eyes on all code, the error was because i greated gamepuzzle before populate the list i just needed to reverse the line addgamepuzzles(); and put it after the line puzzles = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("Sprites/Candy");

Comment: Glad you got that sorted

Comment: Tank you all for the great help

Answer (score 0):

Well In fact the error was easy to find after to me to get eyes on all code, the error was because i greated gamepuzzle before populate the list i just needed to reverse the line addgamepuzzles(); and put it after the line puzzles = Resources.LoadAll ("Sprites/Candy"); 
Like the example

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField]
private Sprite bgimage;

public Sprite[] puzzles;

public List<Sprite> gamepuzzles = new List<Sprite>();

public List<Button> btns = new List<Button>();



void Start () {
    GetButttons();
    AddListeners();

    puzzles = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("Sprites/Candy");
    addgamepuzzles();
}
void GetButttons()
{
    GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PuzzleButton");

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++){
        btns.Add(objects[i].GetComponent<Button>());
        btns[i].image.sprite = bgimage;
    }
}

void addgamepuzzles(){
    int looper = btns.Count;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < looper; i++){

        if (index == looper / 2){
            index = 0;
        }

        gamepuzzles.Add(puzzles[index]);

        index++;
    }
}

void AddListeners(){
    foreach (Button btn in btns){
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => PickPuzzle());
    }
}

public void PickPuzzle(){
    string name = UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
    Debug.Log("you clicked a button with name: " + name);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

puzzles has to be have a defined number of elements before adding to it.  I think you have to do public Sprite[] puzzles = new Sprite[number of elements here];

Comment: Tank you Jamar for comment , i have try to do like you have say but the error continues the same nothing have change